# accessing a vector of objects that has a vector of objects that has a vector of objects from another function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have an object in my main that is a Schedule object called sched.  This object contains a vector of Flight objects called flights and each flight object has a vector of Seat objects called seats.  There's more stuff going on, but this is the part that I'm having trouble with right now.  What I want to do is access and change some of the variables inside these vectors (adding a passenger name to a seat on a specific flight and changing the occupied status of that seat, etc).  I think I have figured out that I need to pass a reference to the flights vector to the function that is gathering the information about the passenger and I'm doing that by placing this function in the Schedule class:

```
vector<Flight>& Schedule::getFlightPtr()
{
    return flights;
}
```

Now how do I use that reference to that vector in the calling function?  This is what I have so far.

```
string passName;
string fltNum;           //yes, the fltNum should be a string
vector<Flight>* flts;

//get the passenger name for the boarding pass and the flight number
cout << "Enter the Passenger's name: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,passName);
cout << "Enter the Flight#: ";
cin >> fltNum;

//get a pointer to the vector of flights in the schedule
*flts = sched.getFlightPtr();

//locate the proper flight and add information to the seat
for (int idx = 0; idx < flts->size(); idx++)
{
        if (*flts[idx]->getFlightNumber() == fltNum)   //<----error states that flts must
        {                                              //have a pointer type on these 3 lines
            *flts[idx]->setSeatName(passName);         //<----
            *flts[idx]->setSeatOccupied() = true;      //<----
        }
}
```

Thanks for any insight you can give me on this problem.

Ok, so now it's compiling and seems to be working, however I cannot get anything to save in my vectors.  Remember, I have nested vectors within vectors.  Do I need to have all of the vectors be passed by reference?

Comment: If you just do `vector<Flight> flts;` it makes your life much easier and code is more modern c++

Answer (score 0):

`*flts = sched.getFlightPtr();` is illegal as you are trying to derefence a null pointer, what you need to do it `std::vector<Flight>& flights = sched.getFlightPtr();` and then use `flights` as a regular `vector` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the asterisk from your `flts`, and change `sched.getFlightPtr()` to `&sched.getFlightPtr()` (or have `getFlightPtr()` return a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
vector<Flight>* flts;

*flts = sched.getFlightPtr();
```

The first line creates a pointer that does not point anywhere yet. But then you dereference it, causing undefined behaviour. In practice , what might happen is for the program to treat a random chunk of memory as if it had a `vector<Flight>` in it.

Instead, you need to create a `vector<Flight>` before you actually try and use it. The simplest way is to replace the first line with:

```
vector<Flight> flts;
```

and remove all your dereferencing operations on `flts`.

You didn't show enough code for me to be sure what is going on in your program. If your intent is to refer to the `flights` that is presumably a member variable of the `Schedule` class (as opposed to taking a copy of that), then you could do:

```
vector<Flight> &flts = sched.getFlightPtr();
```

Then `flts` directly refers to the member of `Schedule`. (BTW this is bad design as it breaks encapsulation).

Comment: I tried changing the line as you suggested, but I get an error on the "sched" part that says "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue:.  I don't want to make any of this constants, because I want to be able to change what's in the vectors. Since I'm breaking encapsulation anyway, what would be a better way to change items in the vectors in my objects?